# Fresh install of ubuntu18.04 gets stuck at the purple screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, asus

I installed ubuntu18.04 several months ago on my desktop and it worked well until today when I tried to turn it on it got stuck at the purple screen (before the ubuntu icon appears).

I looked up online and found this: https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en
but it did not help.

I tried to enter the recovery mode but it gets stuck at the purple screen again.

Next, I reinstalled the ubuntu18.04 by erasing all the disks, unfortunately, that also did not help.

I then tried to reinstall the ubuntu18.04 on another disk and reboot but it failed again.

Now I felt really stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My specs are as the following:
Motherboard: ASUS WS299 SAGE
Graphic Card: RTX 2080 TI
CPU: Intel i9-7940X

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Can you boot into a Live USB session?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, when I use 5.0.0 kernel, it indeed can boot up now!

Comment: @Broadsworde Yes, I can boot into a Live USB session.

Comment: The problem must be with Nvidia drivers that don't build with the 5.3 kernel. What kind of drivers did you install?

Comment: @Pilot6 I believe previously I was using a nvidia driver with version 430.

Comment: Where did you get the driver from? Install the 440 driver from Software & Updates. It should install OK. You can do it with the 5.0 kernel then reboot to the 5.3.

Comment: @Pilot6 I forgot...but probably the same place. When I entered  Software & Updates, there are only 430 and 435 available now so I install 435. After that I reboot to 5.0 and it works and now uses nvidia card for display. However, when I try to boot to 5.3, I still get stuck at the same place (a line showing loading ramdisk).

Comment: OK. It seems that none of the drivers build. I will give a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official drivers don't build with the 5.3 kernel. That's a shame on Ubuntu maintainers. Luckily you can install drivers from a PPA. Run in a terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

and reboot with the 5.3 kernel. It should work.

I had the same trouble with the 390 drivers, but someone told me that the latest do work.

If nothing helps, then stick with the 5.0 kernel for now and report a bug to Launchpad.

The 5.3 kernel must have problems with Nvidia on some systems. I have reports that the PPA drivers or even the official ones do work in some cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, unfortunately, it seems that even after I install 440 and boot to 5.3 (I reinstall the system again and install the 440 driver), it still get stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk ...".

Comment: I can suggest to report a bug against the 5.3 kernel and stick with 5.0 for now.

Comment: I guess that's probably the only thing I can do for now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PLNewbie The "Loading initial ramdisk" error sounds like your /boot/initrd* file is missing or corrupt. Have you tried to create a fresh copy with `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.3.x-generic`?