# I got stuck in 1024x768 resolution, is there a solution?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, display-resolution, xrandr

I got stuck after getting into a terminal by inadvertently pressing a combination of buttons, from which I tried to escape by typing "escape" and then my pc booted after it's loading process I establish a change on the resolution. After reading about this I tried to follow this solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i
but after typing 
`xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00
```

This error message pops up, it doesn't show what my display name is. And I'm stuck.

`sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1f:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: This is related to kernel update to 5.3.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fresh install of ubuntu18.04 gets stuck at the purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204720/fresh-install-of-ubuntu18-04-gets-stuck-at-the-purple-screen)

Comment: Boot with the 5.0 kernel using grub menu.

Comment: No, I even tried different nvidia-driver-430 because after running "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa" somewhere in the procession was written Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-430` (430.40)

Comment: I mean that booting with the previous kernel should fix the issue.

Comment: Change it to 
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-37-generic" and nothing happened I don't if that's the problem.